# UITableView does not transition to next view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm working on a project and have run into a road block. I've searched everywhere and tried everything I found in blogs, other Stack Overflow posts etc. But nothing is working.

Here's my issue.

I'm attempting to create a chat app that will open messages when a particular person is clicked/tapped. I have the opening UI pretty well done, but I can't get the transition to happen. I started working on the project in storyboard, and then switched to mostly code.

My code for the chat controller is as follows:

```
    //**My attempt at creating the transition**

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let controller = ChatLogController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
        controller.friend = messages?[indexPath.item].friend
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
    }
}
```

The View that I am attempting to transition to and pass data

```
import UIKit

class ChatLogController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    var friend: Friend?{
        didSet{

        }
    }
    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

[image: Image of the chat UI at present]

Comment: 1. What does Xcode debugger tell you when you step through? You **must** tell what/where goes wrong. 2. Please delete **all** lines that don't matter, your post is way too long and the majority has nothing todo with your issue.  There are also random empty lines and commented out code; most of us do this sometimes, but don't bother other people with it.  3. Minimizing your code may also help you find the cause.

Comment: Looks like you don't have your controller wrapped inside a Navigation Controller. You can do that on a storyboard by selecting your viewcontroller then going to Editor -> Embed in -> Navigation Controller.  I'm pretty sure when you call it right now it's nil

Comment: @meaning-matters I'm new to iOS development...that said, the debugger didn't give me any errors...it just didn't do anything, which is often times worse than errors, especially at 1-2am lol. Thanks for the tip though

Comment: @jnwagstaff Hey, thanks for the help man! that worked like a charm!! First try at that lol. Can you add your comment as an answer so I can accept it? Thanks again

Comment: "the debugger didn't give me any errors" Because you didn't _have_ any errors. The line `self.navigationController?.pushViewController` means: "If I'm in a navigation controller, go on to the next view controller; if I'm not, do nothing." You're not, so we do nothing. We did exactly what you said to do — nothing.

Comment: @JoelCarter Done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that you have your UIViewController embed within a navigation controller otherwise it will be nil. You can do that on a storyboard by selecting your UIViewController then going to Editor -> Embed in -> Navigation Controller.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have embedded your view controller with navigation controller.